# PHP Include function is not displaying anything

Tags: php, html, include

I'm pretty new to web development and I am trying to learn by trying to develop a website of course. However, I am hitting an issue, I don't get why my include function in PHP is not working.

My 'menu.php' file contains:

```
<?php
echo '
            <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">button1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">button2</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">button3</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">button4</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">button5</a></li> ';
    ?>
```

My html file contains the following:

```
...
<nav>
   <ul>
      <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
   </ul>
</nav> 
...
```

What am I missing? If I copy the list items from my .php to my .html, it works properly.
It works:

```
 ...
    <nav>
       <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">button1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">button2</a></li>            
                <li><a href="#">button3</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">button4</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">button5</a></li> 
       </ul>
    </nav> 
 ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your HTML file won't parse PHP unless it has a `.php` extension (or your server's been configured to parse .html files as PHP files).

Comment: What do you mean? My 'index.html' should be 'index.php' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

> My html file contains the following:

Do you mean that you have a file like `index.html`? Because that means that PHP is not being parsed. All that's happening is that you have a weird `<?php>` element that gets silently ignored as invalid HTML.

Try renaming your file to `index.php` instead.

As an aside, you should always use the browser's View Source option before saying it doesn't do anything ;)

Comment: Exactly, I had index.html. This is exactly what I wanted to know. w3schools wasn't really specific about this matter. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MrSilent w3schools is a very, *very* **bad** reference. See http://w3fools.com/. When learning PHP, the best reference is the [Word of God](http://php.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put PHP content in an HTML file, it won't be processed as such. You should rename your .html page to .php.